# Error when opening previous android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-version

I need to open a previousely developed android application in Eclipse. The application has developper for the `Android 1.6` target. When I import the project to the eclipse IDE it gives the following error.

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

After that:
`Right click the the Project -> Android tools -> Fix project properties`

Still I can't open the project. Does any one have experience this before or have any idea to get rid of this error.

Thans inadvance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android you should use JDK 1.5 (5.0) or 1.6 (6.0). In your case you use JDK 1.7, and Android throws error about this.

Comment: Do you mean java JDK 1.7 Doesn't support Android Developing yet? is it? I have installed JDK 1.7 in my computer.

Comment: Android SDK does not support JDK 1.7 yet. Maybe this will change in the near future but now you should use only 1.5 and 1.6 versions.

Comment: Is it okay to use Eclipse Indigo version bacause I am Using that? ( IDE for Java Developers [Version: Indigo Service Release 1] )

Comment: Yes, you can use Indigo. Android SDK does not depend on the version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that android 1.6 must be  installed on your machine. Secondly java compiler 5.0 or 6.0 must be there if you not have download and installed.

So Set the appropriate java compiler for compilence.
For doing it--> Right click on project->properties->java compiler.

you can also change build target for the project by--> Right click on project->properties->Android

Comment: Yes I have installed android 1.6. Is Eclipse Indigo version has a problem in android developing? ( IDE for Java Developers
[Version: Indigo Service Release 1] )

Comment: When Right click on project->properties->java compiler, it shows java compiler compliance as 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you have entered a wrong Java version, you asked for 1.7 (which is not Java 7 as some are referring) when it requires at least Java 5.

So try to change the version from 1.7 to 7 or to the one you have.

This is done in the manifest file I think